# Assign colour to specific data in Highcharts depending on data type dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a pie chart that displays a number of waste types that are recycled. The client is demanding that specific waste types should be displayed using specific colours. So, for example, Glass should be Blue and Grass should be Green.

I'm using Highcharts, and the pie chart that's used just gives a colour randomly to a data type. Is it possible to tell Highcharts to give a colour to specific waste types? I think I would need to provide colours to at least 10 types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Each data element can be given as an object, where the `color` parameter is provided and set by yourself.

For example:

```
data: [
    {
        name: 'Grass',
        y: 20,
        color: 'green'
    },
    {
        name: 'Glass',
        y: 50,
        color: 'blue'
    },
    {
        name: 'Electronics',
        y: 10,
        color: 'gray'
    }
]
```

Or take a look at [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m20xsrmm/).